# Analog signal level shifting and opamp selection advice

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, analog, signal

I wanted to read out and output 5-ish volt analog signals from a 3.3v mcu.

So basically the signal (roughly 0.25v to 4.5v) first has to be level shifted "down", processed and then level shifted back "up".

I wanted the shifting down and up to be tied together ratio-wise. So what solution I ended up with was basic resistive divider for the ADC and a "reverse" resistive divider (shown below) for the DAC. Resistors used being in an array, so very closely matched.

Out of all this I have two questions:

1. Is the solution I arrived at more-or-less sensible? Anything better out there?
2. Which opamp would you recommend for this application? I've never had to deal with opamps and am having a hell of a time trying to pick a specific one.

[image: reverse resistive divider]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122472/discussion-on-question-by-ben-tait-analog-signal-level-shifting-and-opamp-select).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to divide the input signal down to the MCU voltage to read on an ADC then do some processing to put out a another signal with the DAC of your MCU and translate that to 5V.

You are right that a resistive divider would work to divide the voltage down. An amplifier can be used to step up the voltage. The circuit would look like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frIKrD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The first part is an op amp buffer into a voltage divider to change the signal from a 5V signal to a 3.3V. The second part is a non inverting amplifier to change the 3.3V to a 5V signal.

Also, the op amps should be "rail to rail" meaning the output voltage can go to the power supply rails. Non rail to rail op amps may not be able to swing to the high or low voltages near the power rails if those are needed in your application

Comment: It's good that we've established that my approach would work, but given the same task, what would be your preferred solution? Something similar or maybe entirely different?

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZnx6U.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Your circuit is not doing anything particularly useful for you.  Your Red \$U_{OUT}\$ is completely equal to your Blue \$U_{IN}\$, and the blue \$U_{OUT}\$ is equal to (blue) \$U_{IN} \left(1 + \frac{R_1}{R_2} \right)\$, which will always have a gain greater than 1.0.  There is no scaled down voltage, end there is no level shift anywhere.

I'd love to help you more, but I don't understand your requirements well enough.

The below circuit gives you an attenuation of roughly 2/3 the input signal (a factor of R2/R1), and a pure buffered copy of the input signal.

Comment: Illustration only depicts the amplifier part of the system. Whole point of it is that it uses the regular resistive divider as a governor for setting the amplifier gain at 1/A where A is the division ratio of the resistive divider. So basically, if I have a (separate) resistive divider to divide the signal, and then the illustrated circuit (with same resistor values) as an amplifier, the net gain of the system will be 1.

Comment: I still don't understand your offset requirements.

Answer (score 1):

To have a very similar output as input and only slightly change it I can offer the following to be at least part of what you want to do.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2finT81.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using the OPAmp as a buffer provides minimal load to the signal you want to convert inspect with your ADC. The resistors just before the adc input scale the voltage down to half its buffered value.

The signal in is passed onto an opamp configured to provide you with a voltage offset block. (although it can be used for more than just offsetting the signal at a constant voltage)

Formula for the offset block is
[image]

Where *V_in* is "signal in" and *V_dacOffset* is "Dac V_offset"

Set all the resistance values to 10k and you get V_out = V_dacOffset - V_in

To Scale the signal, you could use programmable resistors and play with the ratios within the formula. or incorporate some jfets and play in their linear region, but easiest would probably be to get a  Programmable gain amplifier and add it to the chain on the top.

Depending on how fast your signal is, you can using the Dac v_offset to alter the signal.. by creating the signal which would subtract of add from the original one, thereby conserving its original form as best as possible.

Comment: Thank you. Your reply has several ideas I could experiment with. Plus programmable gain amps never even occurred to me, will definitely look into them too.